# Custom-defined type highlighting in Sublime Text

Tags: syntax-highlighting, sublime-text, clang

I am looking for a configuration/combination of plugins + clang (or any other parser) that can allow sublime text to highlight all custom defined types just like it highlights native types such as int, double, char, etc. More specifically I guess the exact implementation would be to traverse all included files (both custom written ones and compiled libraries) and find the names of all defined classes, structs and typedefs and highlight them as types in the rest of the source code.

Do similar configurations exist for other languages such as python, javascript, java?

Comment: Please don't [cross-post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39300870/custom-defined-type-highlighting-in-sublime-text) questions. Choose one site and stick with it.